# Mac M1 not able to map PHP 8.0 as a CLI Interpreter within PhpStorm

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm, homebrew, apple-m1

I'm trying to set up the PhpStorm CLI interpreter on my New M1 Mac Book. PHP 8.0 itself is running fine, but I cannot add it as a CLI Interpreter within PhpStorm.

// installation commands

```
brew install php
brew link php@8.0
```

// `which php`

```
/opt/homebrew/bin/php
```

// `php -v`

```
 PHP 8.0.2 (cli) (built: Feb  4 2021 12:48:26) ( NTS )
    Copyright (c) The PHP Group
    Zend Engine v4.0.2, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
        with Zend OPcache v8.0.2, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
    sebastian@nbch003 ~ %
```

// `php --ini`

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /opt/homebrew/etc/php/8.0
Loaded Configuration File:         /opt/homebrew/etc/php/8.0/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /opt/homebrew/etc/php/8.0/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /opt/homebrew/etc/php/8.0/conf.d/error_log.ini,
/opt/homebrew/etc/php/8.0/conf.d/ext-opcache.ini,
/opt/homebrew/etc/php/8.0/conf.d/php-memory-limits.ini
```

Usually, within the PhpStorm CLI Interpreter Settings, I map just the Path to the Current PHP Installation, but this time, PhpStorm does not recognize the PHP 8.0 Interpreter.

[image]

[image]

Compared to my old setup, on this path, no `bin` folder is present to select.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not a Mac user ... but on your screenshot: the path to PHP executable -- I see just a folder path -- I do not see the actual file name part... I suggest you to provide the full path to the PHP executable file.

Comment: Than you, I've added a Screenshot of the files within the folder. Usually, there is a bin folder present where I then can select a php interpreter.

Comment: `which php` (or is it `where php`) and see what it shows there

Comment: From what I know... right now with your current path it looks for `/opt/homebrew/etc/php/8.0/php` file ... which is not there (as per your 2nd screenshot)

Comment: P.S. And it's PhpStorm and not PHP Storm.

Comment: The path was just there to open the second screenshot. I tried to select each single within the folder.

Comment: Find out what file gets executed when you run `php -v`. Normally that is done with `which php`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "PHP Executable" path in PhpStorm is not for the configuration directory, it's for the "php" binary itself.

Running `which php` on your terminal should reveal the linked interpreter path.

It's probably something like `/opt/homebrew/bin/php`.

Comment: The PHP binary on the Default installation is under the path  /usr/bin/php here is just showing PHP 7.3.24. but there is no php.ini file.

Comment: which php outputs => /opt/homebrew/bin/php

Comment: But this is exactly my problem. The path you are relating /usr/local/opt/php@8.0/bin/php. , the bin folder is not present.

Comment: if you share the output `which php` (and you found it that way) I can add it to the answer

Comment: Thank you, the php -v was not helping but the which php was showing the correct path.

Answer (score 0):

the php executable path is in /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.1.7/bin/php

Comment: Welcome to SO. While this answer may be correct for your installation, this must not be the case in general.